# XML+XSD (pay1+ | pay2* | pay3* | pay4*)+

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to construct a xsd scheme to validate a xml.
The xml is:

```
<payments>
  <pay3>5.1</pay3>
  <pay1>1</pay1>
  <pay2>50</pay2>
  <pay3>2</pay3>
</payments>
```

Tags `<pay2>`, `<pay3>` and `<pay2>` are optional and `<pay1>` is mandatory. All the `<payX>` tags may occur in any order and more than once or not to occur (except for `<pay1>`).
So far I made the following xsd types but it is not working correctly if `<pay1>` is not present:

```
<xs:simpleType name="TPayment">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:pattern value="[+]?\d+(\.\d{2})?" />
      <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="TECR_Payments">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="pay1" type="TPayment" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="pay2" type="TPayment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="pay3" type="TPayment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="pay4" type="TPayment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

How to set that `<pay1>` is mandatory?

Comment: Your schema is missing. Could you edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your `TECR_Payments` type:

```
<xs:complexType name="TECR_Payments">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="pay2" type="TPayment" />
      <xs:element name="pay3" type="TPayment" />
      <xs:element name="pay4" type="TPayment" />  
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="pay1" type="TPayment" />
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="pay1" type="TPayment" />
      <xs:element name="pay2" type="TPayment" />
      <xs:element name="pay3" type="TPayment" />
      <xs:element name="pay4" type="TPayment" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This allows any number (including zero) of `<pay2>`, `<pay3>`, or `<pay4>` elements in any order, then requires one `<pay1>`, and then allows any number of `<payX>` elements in any order.

Note that specifying `minOccurs` or `maxOccurs` on an `xs:element` inside an `xs:choice` doesn't really have the effect you want: The choice is first made between the type of element, and *then* the choice is made about how many elements of that type to use.